# How can I input a publisher as a parameter to a function?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning on defining the following publisher in a main() file

```
 ros::Publisher pub_navigation_msg = nh.advertise<rtklib::Navigation>("nav_topic", 10);
```

But I want to use publisher inside my function so I want to define it as a parameter to the function like

```
static void myfunct(ros::Publisher pub, stream mymsg){
.....
.....
pub.publish(mymsg);

}
```

I think I cannot define a publisher outside a main() file because main would consist of Nodehandler and other important ros features.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75457/how-can-i-input-a-publisher-as-a-parameter-to-a-function?/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2017-08-08**:
how do you do it finally? I want to use in different files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how publisher react to copying (my guess is it would be safe), but it should be better to just pass it by reference here.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this statement in your original post is probably *false*:

> I think I cannot define a publisher outside a main() file because main
> would consist of Nodehandler and other important ros features.

ROS creates one node for each executable process.  This is set up by your `ros::init()` call.  You can then create as many `NodeHandle` as you want.  Each NodeHandle points to the same underlying ROS node.  It's typical to create a single NodeHandle and re-use it wherever needed, but that's not a requirement.  The only requirement is that you must call `ros::init()` before creating any `NodeHandle` objects.

So, if needed, you can just create a new NodeHandle inside your function and use that to construct the publisher you need.  Note that this may not be the best design, if your function is called frequently.  Creating a new NodeHandle is cheap, but creating a new publisher involves advertising a new topic to the ROS master and connecting to any subscriber nodes, which can be "expensive".

If you call the function each time you want to publish a new message, then you should declare the publisher external to the function:

- as a global var (use a boost::shared_ptrros::Publisher to make sure it gets created after the ros::init() call)
- as a class member variable
- passed to the function by reference (probably the easiest)
- passed to the function by boost::shared_ptrros::Publisher

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2